# dropdown menu with listview builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, dropdown, appbar

I have a listview.builder in flutter and every item of the list has a dropdown now whenever I select one dropdown value of every dropdown changes. how can I fix this problem in flutter?

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: i found the solution thank u

Comment: https://rsainik80.medium.com/dropdown-button-inside-listview-builder-in-flutter-e2eb74fb45b4

Comment: check my article : -  https://rsainik80.medium.com/dropdown-button-inside-listview-builder-in-flutter-e2eb74fb45b4

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after spending a couple of hours on this and not finding a satisfactory answer (but a lot of hints) I worked it out.

I made a new StatefulWidget class that wraps the DropdownButton.  It is instantiated with the List of items for the dropdown.

**listview_dropdownbutton.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListviewDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<dynamic> sizes;
  const ListviewDropdownButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.sizes,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListviewDropdownButton> createState() => _ListviewDropdownButton();
}

class _ListviewDropdownButton extends State<ListviewDropdownButton> {
  List<dynamic>? _sizes;
  String _currentSize = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _sizes = _sizes ?? widget.sizes;
    _currentSize = _currentSize != '' ? _currentSize : widget.sizes[0];
    return DropdownButton<dynamic>(
      value: _currentSize,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      items: _sizes!.map<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>((dynamic size) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: size,
          child: Text(size),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (dynamic size) {
        if (_currentSize != size) {
          setState(() {
            _currentSize = size!;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In the parent widget, just include the class and use it where you'd put the DropdownButton.

Here's a working example.
**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'listview_dropdownbutton.dart';

void main() => runApp(const DropdownButtonApp());

class DropdownButtonApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DropdownButtonApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('DropdownButton In ListView')),
        body: Center(
          child: DropdownButtonExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownButtonExample extends StatelessWidget {
  DropdownButtonExample({super.key});

  final List<String> _items = <String>['Shirt', 'T-Shirt', 'Pants', 'Blouse', 'Coat'];
  final List<String> _sizes = <String>['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'X-Large'];

  String _currentSize = 'Small';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _items.length,
      itemBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        int index,
      ) {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(_items[index]),
            Row(
              children: [
                ListviewDropdownButton(
                  sizes: _sizes,
                ),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: _currentSize,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  items: _sizes.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String size) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: size,
                      child: Text(size),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (String? size) {
                    if (_currentSize != size) {
                      // setState(() {
                      _currentSize = size!;
                      // });
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Divider(
              thickness: 2,
              height: 2,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

To illustrate it works, I put both the ListviewDropdownButton and a regular DropdownButton in the ListView.

I added `String _currentSize = 'Small';` and the `onChanged` method to show the regular DropdownButton **does not** work.  It never changes from "Small", which was my original problem.

[image: DropdownButton In ListView Screenshot]